# How does one compute the Taylor series of this piece-wise function?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

I need to compute the Taylor series about the origin, for $$f(x)=\frac{e^x -1}{x},\enspace x\neq0$$

and $f(x) = 1, \enspace x=0$. I don't think this should be possible, for $$f'(x) = \frac{(e^x)x-(e^x-1)}{x^2}$$

and this implies not a single one of the derivatives of this function is even defined at the origin. How can we then compute the Taylor series at the origin? Or is it, that in this case each derivative is just trivially zero?

Comment: @IrbidMath The function is continuous at $0$

Comment: No, it is not a pole !

Comment: The Taylor series is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{x^{n-1}} {n!}$

Comment: Take the Taylor series of $e^x$ about $x=0$, subtract $1$ from it and then divide each term by $x$. You are done!

Comment: @IrbidMath No, it's a removable singularity.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yeah I noticed that I was on the phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: with the power series of $e^x$ we get

$$f(x)=1+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+....$$

for all $x \in \mathbb R.$

Comment: So, when you expand $e^x$ at zero, it is implicitly assumed that $x\neq 0$. And this is why it can be plugged in to the function expression?

Comment: @variations Exactly, and then you observe that it continues to hold at $x=0$ too since it agrees with the definition ($f(0)=1$).